# Multiple VPNs with one fixed external IP

Tags: networking, vpn

I am in a shared working space, sharing with around 100 other companies. Lots of the companies need a VPN between them and developers working externally. The office has a very limited number of external IPs, and the ISP's cost for adding to them is prohibitive.

So is it possible to use some kind of hardware / software configuration to have all VPN traffic come through on custom ports? Our (external) tech support provider says it's not possible, because there are only a limited number of ports that the VPN can work through.

I found this question - [Multiple VPN Connections, One IP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/256631/multiple-vpn-connections-one-ip) - but I don't really understand VPNs well enough to discuss the solution with the ISP or tech support.

What type of VPN do we need to set up? What kind of hardware (if any) could support our requirements?

Comment: VPN is very wide term, what kind of VPN? IPSec, or a SSL-based VPN like OpenVPN?

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha Intentionally vague, as different companies have different requirements. However, if the answer was "you can only do this with OpenVPN" then we could at least say that. At present, the answer is "You can't do this".

Comment: IPSec GW can have many VPNs on one IP. Problem is your silly question, sorry.

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha Apologies if the question seems silly to you - as somebody who doesn't really understand IPSec GW, it's not so silly to me.

Comment: Seems to me that the question is how to provide a bunch of different developers VPN access to a bunch of different servers - and the servers are all behind a single IP address.  

You need to specify exactly what sort of access the developers need
as it may just be a case of providing SSH or FTP access to some servers rather than a VPN joining the developers network to your network.

If that is too complex, maybe you should focus on your own problem, and let the 100 other companies worry about theirs.

Comment: @dunxd Sorry, should have said in the question - I work directly for the building owner, so have been asked to get this sorted. We don't have a dedicated sysadmin (I'm a web developer), as our IT support company do all that stuff for us. It's that company that's saying "it can't be done", and I'm looking into whether there is a way, which I can then tell them to do. Your description of the problem is exactly right, and the companies have definitely asked for VPN access. I need to give a solution, or at least know which questions I have to ask.

Comment: Your IT support company is staffed by idiots.  It is both possible to run multiple VPNs on the one server, and to run multiple VPN servers on the one IP (via different ports).

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple IPSec tunnels using a single IP address.

I tend to use Vyatta's, as a virtual router, which I create in my XenServer pools.

Vyatta's are quite easy to configure and there is a lot of documentation to go with it.

Here is a [guide to creating multiple IPSec tunnels](http://www.vyatta.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=7190&sid=79abd36d07e009fab2c825ab4489fd9b):

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of (soft|hard)ware firewalls can manage multiples IPSec VPN with a single external IP. Alternatively you may just have to NAT certains services to give remote users the requested functionnalities.